# Is there a way to return data according to properties in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In each of my nodes I have a selection of properties like `education_id` , `work_id`, `locale` etc etc. All these properties can have one or more than one values of the sort of `education_id:112` or `education_id:165` i.e. Node A might have `education_id:112` and Node B might have `education_id:165` and again Node C might have `education_id:112` and so on.

I want a **cypher query** that return all nodes for a particular value of the property and I don't care about the value of the property beforehand.

To put it into perspective, in the example I have provided, it must return Node A and Node C under `education_id:112` and Node B under `education_id:165`

Note: I am not providing multiple cypher queries specifying the values of properties each time. The whole output must be dynamic.

The output to the query should be something like

`education_id:112 Node A, Node C`

`education_id:165 Node B`

These are the results of a single query statement.

Comment: I understand that the downvoters thought I have not made any research, and this was easy to find in the Cypher refcard. What has been the problem though, there has been a misunderstanding and I have not been able to explain the content of my question clearly.

Comment: I do not know, how can I improve the question more, with code or anything such, because, I do not have any idea about what to write in the code, and that is exactly what I am looking for,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your question, but based on the expected output:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n.education_id,collect(n)
```

will group nodes by distinct values of education_id

Comment: I apologize if I have not been able to frame the question clearly. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at the [cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/). What you are looking for is the `WHERE`clause:

`Match (a) WHERE a.education_id = 112 return a`

You can also specify property directly in the `MATCH` clause.

`Match (a{education_id: 112}) RETURN a`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. I have specifically said in my Note, I will not provide multiple queries with the values of the properties.